# Python multiple lists of different lengths, averages and standard deviations

Tags: python, list, mean, stdev

Given the array of lists below, i want to be able to create a new list, giving the average and standard deviation of the columns

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2],
      [7, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Required result

```
mean =  2.8, 2.6, 3.75, 5
STDEV=  2.48997992, 0.894427191, 0.957427108, 1.414213562
```

I found the below example to give averages, which seems to work very well, but i wasnt clear how to adapt this for the standard deviation

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2],
      [7, 2, 3, 4]]


averages = [np.ma.average(ma.masked_values(temp_list, None)) for temp_list in zip_longest(*a)]


print(averages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these two lines:

```
>>> np.nanmean(np.array(list(zip_longest(*a)),dtype=float),axis=1)
array([2.8 , 2.6 , 3.75, 5.  ])

>>> np.nanstd(np.array(list(zip_longest(*a)),dtype=float),axis=1,ddof=1)
array([2.48997992, 0.89442719, 0.95742711, 1.41421356])
```

[`nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) and [`nanstd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html) compute mean and std respectively, and ignoring `nan`. So you are passing it the array:

```
>>> np.array(list(zip_longest(*a)),dtype=float)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  7.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5., nan,  3.],
       [nan, nan,  6., nan,  4.]])
```

And computing the mean and standard deviation for each row, ignoring `NaN`s. The `ddof` argument stands for degrees of freedom, and I set it to 1 based on your desired output (default is 0)

Comment: Just handing over the solution without documenting it is no good except that it can just be applied to this particular problem without an easy way to apply it to other similar problems. Perhaps you can add some info what you are doing in these attractive one-liners

Comment: as simple as that! :-) thank you, that worked perfectly

Comment: @Bazingaa, you're right, it was a bit of a lazy answer! I've added a bit more info.